# Adding tab completion to a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete

I am creating a script which does some processing on a file. For the file, Ι will select any file from the current directory or will give path to a file.

Problem is the file name can be huge, so typing it all will be a pain.

```bash
echo "Enter file name"
read FILE
```

The above code demonstrate what I am trying to do. When running this script, I have to put the file name character by character, which will be a huge pain. I want to get suggestions like in any terminal application by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I want something like this [image: Something like this] to show up on pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> while writing the file name. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just pass the filename on the command line? It's a bit more Unix-y, and you get tab completion for free...

Comment: @RogerLipscombe that's a good idea too, but some times i have to choose the file depending on how script is going.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can read the input filename like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "Enter filename: " f
printf "filename: %s\n" "$f"
```

`read -e` uses `readline` which has already tab-completion for paths. `read --help` and `man readline` for details about them.